# How to merge all identical materials into one?

Tags: materials, append

I have made some trees to make a forest and each tree has its own file. Now I have appended them into one file and now I have like 40 unnecessary materials which are completely the same and each is assigned to a few objects, so that I would have to switch materials for about 200 objects to get rid of them. Is there some other way to merge the identical materials into a single material?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Select all the objects that share the same material. Using *Select->Select Pattern* may be a quick way to do that.
- <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> -> Material will set the same material for each object.